# web browser control scrollto works but then reverts to 0

Tags: browser, scroll, scrollto

So I'm trying to show users a preview of some HTML they've typed in by using a web browser control to render it as they change the HTML.  This works fine, except that the browser scrolls to the top after each change. So I put this in:

```
    private void txtTemplateText_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int top = 0;
        if (this.webBrowser.Document != null) top = this.webBrowser.Document.Body.ScrollTop;
        this.webBrowser.DocumentText = this.txtTemplateText.Text;
        if (this.webBrowser.Document != null) this.webBrowser.Document.Window.ScrollTo(0, top);
    }
```

in the text changed event of the textbox where they're entering the HTML. If I step through this code, everything is working correctly. The values are what I expect. When I execute the ScrollTo line, everything looks right, but when I F10 off the closing brace, the browser control's scroll position goes back to 0, even though there is no additional code being executed after that line.

If I hard-code the value to 1000 (instead of the variable top), I can actually see the scroll position being correctly set and then it going back to 0.

I can't imagine what is resetting this value and causing the scrolled position to change after it was correct.

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe this worked.  I had to put this line before the ScrollTo line:

```
Application.DoEvents(); // must have this so document has been loaded before trying to set scroll, otherwise it goes to top
```

I'm assuming that the document hasn't actually loaded (even when stepping through), so setting the scroll property doesn't work at that point because there's nothing to scroll to, even through it looks like there is.